# Stop pandas from silently converting numbers exceeding dtype limits

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to read a csv file into pandas.DataFrame. While reading I do specify dtype. Sometimes data input doesn't meet dtype requirements and pandas silently (!) converts the input. I'd like that operation to raise an exception.

Here's my code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
my_csv = StringIO('foo\n1\n-1')
my_df = pd.read_csv(my_csv, dtype=pd.np.uint8)
my_df
```

The output:

```
   foo
0    1
1  255
```

`-1` was converted into `255` as it doesn't fit into [np.uint8](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) limits.

The questions are:

1) Why did it pass silently?

2) How to make pandas raise an exception when input doesn't fit into dtype limits (or probably make NumPy raise it as it does the same thing when `my_arr = pd.np.array([1, -1], dtype=pd.np.uint8)`)?

Comment: Keep in mind that dataframes only support int64 as integer types.

Comment: @coldspeed what do you mean by "supports"? `my_df.dtypes` shows correct `foo    uint8`

Comment: Ah, that's news to me.. okay, is there the chance you are reading in floats and using np.uint8 to truncate them to int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be `pandas` being too helpful, you could define your own func and pass this to `converters` to check if the values are within the numeric limits for a given `dtype`:

```
In[28]:

import numpy as np
import io
typ = np.uint8
def foo1(x):
    if np.iinfo('uint8').min > np.int(x) < np.iinfo('uint8').max :
        raise ValueError('{0} outside numeric limits'.format(x))
    return x
# df creation code from @coldspeed
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('foo\n1\n-1'), converters={'foo':foo1})
df
```

raises:

```
      4 def foo1(x):
      5     if np.iinfo('uint8').min > np.int(x) < np.iinfo('uint8').max :
----> 6         raise ValueError('{0} outside numeric limits'.format(x))
      7     return x
      8 

ValueError: -1 outside numeric limits
```

## generic solution

```
def foo1(x,dtype):
   if np.dtype(dtype).kind == 'f'
       if np.finfo(dtype).min > np.float64(x) < np.finfo(dtype).max :
   elif np.iinfo(dtype).min > np.int(x) < np.iinfo(dtype).max :
       raise ValueError('{0} outside numeric limits'.format(x))
   return x
```

so you could then call this on all columns:

```
columns = pd.read_csv(...., nrows=1).columns
```

and then zip the columns to make a dict and use the converter:

```
col_converters = dict(zip(columns, foo1))
```

and then pass to `read_csv`:

```
pd.read_csv(..., converters=col_converters)
```

This though expects your data to be a single `dtype`, if you have multiple `dtype`s to validate then you'd need to build your converter dict manually

Comment: Thank you for an answer, it is a working approach. However I'm very surprised NumPy itself doesn't provide control over this behaviour. Do have an idea why it doesn't?

Also you are writing "`pandas` being too helpful". Do you think such behaviour could be helpful in any way whatsoever? I mean who actually wants his numbers being added to the minimum value of a dtype?

Comment: `pandas` is helping by not borking on your data, it allows heterogenous dtypes, and ease of use. This is just one of the things which it does under the hood, you can always suggest an improvement at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues as an enhancement request, note that this behaviour is not necessarily incorrect. Plenty of languages overflow or promote values, this is usually defined somewhere, what you're asking is for strictness to be applied